# XSXsltListViewWebPart embedded search feature does not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

what i could see is that the XSXsltListViewWebPart search feature does not work: i don't know is there any implementation for search:

```
  <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ...>
      <ParameterBindings>
         ...
     </ParameterBindings>
     <DataFields>
        ...
     </DataFields>
     <XmlDefinition>
      ...
     </XmlDefinition>
 </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured search service?

Comment: thanks yousuf but how i could do that, if i should create search center site or configuation in my site.

Comment: Configure the Search Service application from Central administration site.